# How to read <object> <PARAM> properties in ActiveX web control with VC++/MFC

Tags: html, visual-c++, activex

I have ActiveX control done in VC++/MFC. It embeds into html web page. Now I need to be able to configure it by providing parameters in html  tag. like:

     

The question is how do I read those parameters during my ActiveX initialization? My research revealed that it has to be done through IPersistPropertyBag interface, but I could really use some code examples to figure that out.

Any examples in VC++ please?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question...
Basically from ActiveX point of view those HTML  parameters are "persistent storage" parameters.
So in your HTML file:

```
<OBJECT ID="activex1" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=200
    ...
    <PARAM NAME="ServerAddress" VALUE="192.168.1.1:1234">
    ...
</OBJECT>
```

And in your MFC ActiveX control:

```
void Cubcam_activexCtrl::DoPropExchange(CPropExchange* pPX)
{
    ExchangeVersion(pPX, MAKELONG(_wVerMinor, _wVerMajor));
    COleControl::DoPropExchange(pPX);

    // TODO: Call PX_ functions for each persistent custom property.
    PX_String(pPX, _T("ServerAddress"), m_serverAddress, _T(""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting; I will have to try the method you describe.  The way that I know of to do this is to implement the IPersistPropertyBag interface and implement the Load method.

I haven't used MFC, just ATL, but I implemented this by hand.  I will have to look into the solution you provided to see if there are advantages to the underlying approach used by MFC.